# Changing the Dock property in a Winforms user control

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to create a button that will hide the panel that I have docked at the centre of my user control.

My form is laid out like so:

```
toolStrip1 (docked to top)
topPanel (docked to fill)
bottomPanel (docked to bottom)
```

I have the following code:

```
Private Sub ShowHideTopPanel()
    If topPanel.Visible Then
        topPanel.Visible = False
        bottomPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    Else
        topPanel.Visible = True
        bottomPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom
    End If
End Sub
```

This works to an extent.  However, when the `bottomPanel` is set to Fill it seems to fill the entire control, and not just up to `toolStrip1`.  Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and how to correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The z-index of your controls is causing this behaviour. Try to play a little bit with the `[Control].BringToFront()` and `[Control].SendToBack()` methods.